# Creating a Gantt Chart and to fit page correctly in Latex

Tags: tex, gantt-chart, latex-suite

At the moment I have made a Gantt Chart, but as you see from the image you cannot see it properly and looks messy. I have tried to tweak but have had no luck with it. If anyone can help me to make it look better please. This is my first attempt of trying to create a Gantt Chart. Also I have tried making it so that it shows both an active line to where we are currently in the process. Additionally if a task is less then week a way of showing this without making the Gantt Chart exceedingly long. Any suggestions?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/joM2E.jpg

```
\documentclass[final]{cmpreport}

  \subsection{Gantt Chart \& Critical Path}
    \begin{sideways}
      \newganttchartelement{voidbar}{
    voidbar/.style={
        draw=black,
        top color=black!25,
        bottom color=black!23
    }}
    \begin{ganttchart}[x unit=0.27cm, vgrid, title label font=\footnotesize,
        canvas/.style={draw=black, dotted}]{1}{44}
        \gantttitlelist{1,...,22}{2} \\


        %the elements, bars and milestones, are identified as elem0, elem1, etc

        %elem1
        \ganttbar{A.Project Assigned}{1}{2}     \\  %elem0  
        \ganttbar{B. Create Plan}{1}{4}    \\  %elem1 
        \ganttbar{C. Ambassador Requirements}{5}{6}              \\  %elem2
        \ganttbar{D. Recruit Ambassadors} {7}{8} \\
        \ganttbar{E. Communicate with Ambassadors } {9}{10} \\
        \ganttbar {F. Set Marketing Objectives} {11}{11} \\
        \ganttbar {G. Design, publish \& evaluate survey} {11}{14} \\
        \ganttbar {H. Design Marketing Comms} {15}{18} \\
        \ganttbar {I. Execute Plan} {19}{24} \\
        \ganttbar {J. Set Webpage Objectives} {25}{25} \\
        \ganttbar {K. Website Research} {25}{26} \\
        \ganttbar {L. Website Prototype} {27}{28} \\
        \ganttbar {M. Approve design/develop} {28}{29} \\
        \ganttbar {N. Test \& evaluate} {30}{30} \\
        \ganttbar {O. Venue \& theme} {31}{34} \\
        \ganttbar {P. Choose Catering \& Entertainment } {35}{36} \\
        \ganttbar {Q. Final Presentation} {37}{37} \\

        \ganttlink{elem0}{elem2}
        \ganttlink{elem1}{elem2}
        \ganttlink{elem2}{elem3}
        \ganttlink{elem5}{elem6}
        \ganttlink{elem8}{elem9}
        \ganttlink{elem9}{elem10}
        \ganttlink{elem9}{elem11}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{sideways}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a very old question but today I began learning about `pgfgantt` and I found that there is the `expand chart` option for `ganttchart` to resize the diagram. Example:

```
expand chart=1.2\textwidth
```

More info at the `pgfgantt` package documentation:
http://bay.uchicago.edu/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf